# What is the proper way to overwrite the cy.click() command in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I'm trying to build an overwrite for `cy.click()` to add an additional assertion that must be true before an element is clicked. I know I could do this with a custom command, but I'd rather do it by overriding the built in one so that our existing tests all get the fix without having to be updated, and so we don't need to remember to use a different click method in the future.
My current code is:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('click', (originalFn, subject, options) => {
    cy.wrap(subject).should('not.have.attr', 'disabled').then(() => {
        return originalFn(subject,options);
    })
});
```

Basically, it should check one extra assertion (waiting for it to become true, since using `should`) then do the built-in click. My reasoning behind this is that the built in click assertions [don't recognize the disabled attribute on certain elements](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5903) (e.g. `<a>` is always considered enabled even if it has the disabled attribute). This works on tests that just click, but fails with the following message when `cy.type` or `cy.select` are called, possibly because those use click internally?

```
cypress_runner.js:199855 CypressError: Timed out retrying: Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

  > `cy.type()`

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

  > `cy.wrap()`

Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.

Cypress will resolve your command with whatever the final Cypress command yields.

The reason this is an error instead of a warning is because Cypress internally queues commands serially whereas Promises execute as soon as they are invoked. Attempting to reconcile this would prevent Cypress from ever resolving.
```

I found [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3838), but it got closed without actually giving a solution to this issue. What is the proper way to overwrite click without causing issues with other methods that seem to call it internally?

Comment: What if you use expect(): expect(subject).to.not.have.attr('disabled');
  return originalFn(subject,options);

Comment: Not getting the error, please post the full test. Tried it clicking a button and an `<input type="button"`. The reference to `cy.type()` in the error is suspicious.

Comment: @Ackroydd Clicking a button or input works fine. The issue is when you call `cy.type()` or `cy.select()` with this overwrite, since they seem to call `cy.click()` initially. Adding the overwrite to the kitchen sink example (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink) and running tests that `select` or `type` reproduces the issue.

Comment: @LeonardoMartinez I tried that, but `expect` doesn't wait for the condition to become true like `cy.should()` does. In my case the element is disabled at first and becomes enabled later (by JS code that is loaded asynchronously), so expect fails immediately.

Comment: Woops sorry, bad eyesight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the issue referenced, I don't think there's a "proper" way to overwrite click, but for your use-case a solution is to look at the force option.

When `.type()` issues a click it sets the force option, see [type.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/012d58c228851b089d04efe5bf9834c83e0c198d/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/actions/type.js#L413)

> force: true, // force the click, avoid waiting

Same with [select.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/012d58c228851b089d04efe5bf9834c83e0c198d/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/actions/select.js#L211)

And since `force` ignores disabled attributes, there's no need to check disabled when calling `.click({force: true})`.

The following seems to work ok, but I'm not sure it covers every scenario

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('click', (originalFn, subject, options) => {

  if (!options?.force) {
    cy.wrap(subject).should('not.have.attr', 'disabled').then(() => {
      return originalFn(subject,options);
    })
  } else {
    return originalFn(subject,options);
  }
})
```

---

For situations checking something other than `disabled`, there's an ***undocumented*** state property `current` which gives the command type

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('click', (originalFn, subject, options) => {

  const currentCommand = cy.state('current').attributes.name;

  if (currentCommand === 'click') {
    cy.wrap(subject).should('not.have.attr', 'disabled').then(() => {
      return originalFn(subject,options);
    })
  } else {
    return originalFn(subject,options);
  }
})
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and will be added since force should skip this additional check. It does fix `type`, but unfortunately doesn't seem to fix `select` as it issues 2 clicks (presumably one to open the dropdown and a second to pick an option) and only passes force to the second click.
However, this did point me in a helpful direction. All of these internal calls pass `verify: false` to click, which we never pass. So skipping this check in that case seems to solve the issue for now.

Comment: I added the following check and it seems to be working, clicks from my tests do check the new assertion but ones called internally from click, select, etc. do not.
`if (!options || (!options.force && options.verify !== false))`

Comment: IMO overwriting commands is over-rated. I would prefer the more explicit approach of a new command, or just prefix the `click` with `.should('not.have.attr', 'disabled')`.